# Can a cfargument be of type "list"?

Tags: list, coldfusion, arguments, coldfusion-8

I want to have an argument like this:

```
<cfargument 
  name="exclude" 
  type="list" 
  required="false" 
  default="-1" 
  hint="A list of source IDs that should be excluded"
>
```

I don't see it in the docs at http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_a-b_6.html by I don't really trust them.

Does anyone know if this is possible or will I have to convert to an array?

At the moment I get an error:

> The EXCLUDE argument passed to the renderSelectSource function is not of type list.

It's not complaining that "list" is not a valid type, but maybe it's just a bad error message.

Comment: As charlie said, the correct type is probably `string`. Re: The error, since `list` isn't one of the basic types (string, boolean, numeric, ...) CF will assume it is a component name. You probably do not have a `/List.cfc` hence the error.

Answer (score 12):

The type in this case would be "string".  A list is just a string.

You could do the conversion to array... but unless it buys you something that I'm not seeing, I don't see the issue with just declaring the argument as a string.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do in this situation is allow for either a delimited string (i.e. a list) or an array. In particular this lets you deal with situations where your array value contains the delimiter (i.e. a comma). For example:

```
<cffunction name="myFunction" output="false" access="public" returntype="any" hint="">
    <cfargument name="multiValuedArg" type="any" required="true"/>
    <cfif isSimpleValue(arguments.multiValuedArg)>
        <cfset arguments.multiValuedArg = listToArray(arguments.multiValuedArg)>
    <cfelseif NOT isArray(arguments.multiValuedArg)>
        <cfthrow type="java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"
            message="'multiValuedArg' argument must be an array or comma delimited list">
    </cfif>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: type="java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"?  What's the advantage of using that? and does it really throw that obj? or just a string?

Comment: @Henry: the advantage is semantic. When specifying the `type` attribute of a `<cfthrow/>` I try to use existing Java exceptions that align with the intent. So if you review its javadoc: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html you can see how this lines up. I haven't tested to see if under the hood it actually generates a Java exception object of that type, but `<cfcatch type="java.lang.IllegalArgumentException">` will catch a ColdFusion or Java generated exception correctly.