# Coldfusion - Single Item lists

Tags: coldfusion

Not been using CF long, but I have hit (an undoubtedly simple) stumbling block dealing with lists.

I have a component called user that has a list property called roles:

```
property type="List" name="roles"  default="";
```

(I have set accessors=true so get the setter for free)

Now I  want to set the roles as a list, and my understanding (what google tells me) is that initialising lists is just as simple as creating a comma separated string, for example `"USER,ADMIN,SUPER"` etc.

My problem is, I am trying to set it as a single item list:

```
user.setRoles("user");
```

and I am getting the error

```
The roles argument passed to the SETROLES function is not of type List.
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong/what I need to do so CF recognises the single item string as a list?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well lists are really just strings with delimiters.  What if you change the type to string?

Comment: yes, thanks! I also just saw this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282327/can-a-cfargument-be-of-type-list  Will just do that!